# Why collectionView freezes on scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a simple app with photo filters, like Instagram. So, I capture my image then I need to implement filter to this image. On the bottom I have a UICollectionView(horizontal scroll) where I can see what filters I have and how they will look on my image.

But when I scroll my UICollectionView - it freezes and my filters applying on every new cell(because of reusing process). But how Instagram does it that when I scroll the filters they does not freeze?

I've tried this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell: imageFilterCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! imageFilterCell

let queue = NSOperationQueue()

    let op1 = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in
        let img = UIImage(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image!, 0.1)!)
        let img1 = self.applyFilterTo(img!, filter: self.filtersImages[indexPath.row])

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
            cell.imageView.image = img1
        })
    }

    queue.addOperation(op1);

    return cell
}
```

but it still freezes on scroll and I see how every time my filters are applying to my cells. Can I do it just one time and then on scroll to do nothing, just showing how the photo will looks after implementing the filter?

Comment: Try with making you `NSOperationQueue`( `let queue = NSOperationQueue()`) global. define and initialize it once at time of 'ViewDidLoad()` and just `Add Operation` in `CollectionView` Method.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma unfortunately, it did not work. On scroll I still see how my filters implement on my cell's every time =/

Answer (score 3):

You could do one of the two things:

1. Do not use the reuse feature of the collection view. Simply create
   an array of cells and pass those cells to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This should work fine if you
   don't have a large number of filters. Something like:

   ```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       var cell: imageFilterCell? = nil
       if (cellsArray.count <= indexPath.row) {
           //This assumes imageFilterCell is created in code
           //If you use storyboards or xibs load it accordingly
           cell = imageFilterCell()
           cellsArray.append(cell)
       } else {
           cell = cellsArray[indexPath.row]
       }
       let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
          let img = UIImage(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image!, 0.1)!)
          let img1 = self.applyFilterTo(img!, filter: self.filtersImages[indexPath.row])

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                cell!.imageView.image = img1
          }
   }

       return cell
   ```

   }
2. Implement a cancel mechanism for the async operation, because if the cell is reused while the background thread is still applying the filter the final cell will end up having multiple filters. For this you could use the `cancel` method from the `NSOperation` class. For this you could create a property on your custom cell called `operation` something like:

   ```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell: imageFilterCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! imageFilterCell
       cell.operation.cancel()    

       //make the queue an instance variable
       //let queue = NSOperationQueue()

       let op1 = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in
           let img = UIImage(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image!, 0.1)!)
           let img1 = self.applyFilterTo(img!, filter: self.filtersImages[indexPath.row])

           NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
               cell.imageView.image = img1
           })
       }

       queue.addOperation(op1);
       cell.operation = op1

       return cell
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it crashes now with: `reason: 'the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'` I chose the first option. I do not have a XIB. I insert the UIImageView in a storyboard. Look here: http://imgur.com/7Tnnmo1. I've putted it directly in my UIViewController. So, need I change your code?

Comment: Well...then use `collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! imageFilterCell` instead of `imageFilterCell()`. It should still be fine.

Comment: If that doesn't work you should try moving your cell to a xib and load it from there. Storyboards register the cell automatically and you can't create them manually.

Comment: I've added these lines in `viewDidLoad`: `let nib = UINib(nibName: "filterCell", bundle: nil) collectionView.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "filterCell")` but I still get the same error

Comment: it seems it's required to call `dequeReusableCell`

Comment: When I'm trying to print my cell, it prints: `baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 0 0);`

Comment: Don't use `registerNib` in `viewDidLoad` and use `let cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("YourCustomViewNibName", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as YourCustomView` to get the cell

Comment: instead of this `var cell: filterCell? = nil` in collectionView func?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105500/discussion-between-john-doe-and-jelly).

Answer (score 0):

You are processing in the main thread, this is why it freezes.

Use a Concurrent Dispatch Queue for a more fluid experience.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: imageFilterCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! imageFilterCell


   let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
           let img = UIImage(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image!, 0.1)!)
           let img1 = self.applyFilterTo(img!, filter: self.filtersImages[indexPath.row])

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                 cell.imageView.image = img1
           }
    }

        return cell
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work. On scroll I still see how my filters implement on my cell's every time =/

Answer (score 0):

you can cache data (Images) in memory
its problem have a lovely relation with read data(images) :D